# At the same time settings for swiper slider

Tags: swiper.js

I want to set item number for browser screen. Here's the key part:

```
<body>
    <!-- Swiper -->
    <div class="swiper-container mySwiper">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Swiper JS -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
    <script>
      var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
        slidesPerView: 3,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        freeMode: true,
        pagination: {
          el: ".swiper-pagination",
          clickable: true,
        },
      });
    </script>
  </body>
```

And here's [CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/mio1m?file=/index.html). Here I always see 3 items at the same time. I want to set it for 5 slides; how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just change `slidesPerView` value from 3 to the value you'd like to see. Actually you can even set up in a different way for various screen sizes, for example (taken from [official doc page](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api)):

```
breakpoints: {
  // when window width is >= 320px
  320: {
    slidesPerView: 2,
    spaceBetween: 20
  },
  // when window width is >= 480px
  480: {
    slidesPerView: 3,
    spaceBetween: 30
  },
  // when window width is >= 640px
  640: {
    slidesPerView: 4,
    spaceBetween: 40
  }
}
```

... etc. I wasn't able to see those changes in Code Sandbox, but that seems to an issue on their side; the code taken as is works fine on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hdunmt2p/).